# set property for user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

hi i have a userControl with this property :

```
public string UserImg { get; set; }
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            userImg.Src = UserImg;
        }
    }
```

and markup :

```
<img class="userImg" src="" width="90" id="userImg" runat="server" />
```

when i use this userControl and set it in code :

```
StudentDetail1.UserImg = string.Format("AdminPanel/StudentsPic/{0}",query.Pictuer);
```

(query is my linq to entite's query that contain image name like 'person.png').

image is'not displayed,because i have got an extra "UserControl" below:

```
<img src="UserControl/AdminPanel/StudentsPic/man.png" id="right_StudentDetail1_userImg" class="userImg" width="90">
```

how can i remove "UserControl" from src.

Comment: so your image existing in `AdminPanel/StudentsPic/` folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
StudentDetail1.UserImg = string.Format("../AdminPanel/StudentsPic/{0}",query.Pictuer);
```

Comment: It's a good idea to explain your answers, rather than just pasting code.